# Google play configuration to push different APKs for different Android versions

Tags: android, google-play, android-version

At the moment we have two app versions in production:
[image]
as you may see, we have version 1420028 for API levels 19+ and 218 for API levels 7+

Now we've prepared a build for API levels from 16 to 18

We see following error after uploading that build to the GP:
[image]

Frankly I can't get what following error message says, it looks grammatically incomplete to me.

> This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
>
> It is forbidden that a device upgrading from API levels in range 16-18 to API levels in range 19+ should downgrade from version 1420029 to version 218, which would occur when
>
> Screen layouts containing any of [small@mdpi, small@hdpi, small@xhdpi, small@xxhdpi, normal@mdpi, normal@hdpi, normal@xhdpi, normal@xxhdpi, large@mdpi, large@hdpi, large@xhdpi, large@xxhdpi] and
>
> Features containing all of [android.hardware.LOCATION, android.hardware.location.GPS, android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN, android.hardware.WIFI].

Any way to achieve configuration explained above? Is it a Google Play bug or just me getting something wrong?

Comment: Can you use a version code lower than 1420028 for the new version?

Comment: @nasch, that version would be just skipped, as having version code lower than which is already publisher